# "title attribute" "font face"

Tags: html, css, fonts

You hover a mouse you get a tooltip - but what if you want something that requires a different font face, a character set with that one glyph - not that there isn't a workaround, the words that describe it will suffice, the alternative characters that resemble it - but let's be professional about this, e.g. a **double bemolle** is a character and it's available to use in FreeSerif, just not it seems in the title attribute [i.e. *not* the title tag]....

I can use style,

```
<style>
button.serif {
    font-family: FreeSerif;
}
</style>
```

& then my buttons will display the character,

```
<button class="serif" title="" style="width: 3.02cm; height: 0.9cm; background-color:#FFFFFF">Push  Button</button>
```

...but as you can see here if you create this html file, where the title attribute is given, it doesn't however work.

So you go looking at style again and to see if there's anything, then peruse web search results that seem to point at jquery, or contemplate trying something with ezpz-tooltip, but to no avail if you'd hope to just type something like,

```
<style>

button.serif {
    title font-family: FreeSerif;
}
</style>
```

...or if it *is* something like this - the number of permutations to trial & error, like,

title.font-family,

title-font-family,

title: font-family,

"title font-family",

"title" font-family,

'title' font-family,

etc.

...or simply where to properly research this in the standard texts?

...So, any pointers...?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to style the browser native tooltip used to render the title attribute.

As you pointed out in the question, the only work around is to use a different way to create the tooltip.